# Date Filter with AMPScript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, code, filters

I am trying to pull out Tracking Event data, using the "TrackingEvent" Object Type. I need to find tracking event data for a subscriber within the last 30 days.

How do I create a simplefilterpart condition that can take in a date and use "greaterThan" (or a date range)?

Here's my sample code: (It doesn't seem to pull back any record- it should)

```
%%[

SET @client = CreateObject("ClientID")
SetObjectProperty(@client, "ID", "12345678")
SetObjectProperty(@client, "IDSpecified", "true")

SET @rr = CreateObject("RetrieveRequest")
SetObjectProperty(@rr, "ObjectType", "TrackingEvent")
AddObjectArrayItem(@rr,"ClientIDs",@client)
SetObjectProperty(@rr,"QueryAllAccounts",1)
AddObjectArrayItem(@rr,"Properties","SendID")
AddObjectArrayItem(@rr,"Properties","CreatedDate")
AddObjectArrayItem(@rr,"Properties","ModifiedDate")
AddObjectArrayItem(@rr,"Properties","SubscriberKey")

SET @sf1 = CreateObject("SimpleFilterPart")
SetObjectProperty(@sf1, "Property", "CreatedDate")
SetObjectProperty(@sf1, "SimpleOperator", "greaterThan")
AddObjectArrayItem(@sf1, "Value", DateAdd("02/01/2016", "0", "d"))

SET @sf2 = CreateObject("SimpleFilterPart")
SetObjectProperty(@sf2, "Property", "SubscriberKey")
SetObjectProperty(@sf2, "SimpleOperator", "equals")
AddObjectArrayItem(@sf2, "Value", "ssaltzman@fulcrumtech.net<mailto:myemail@somedomain.net>")

/* So, for this complex filter we're filtering for ListID and EmailAddress */
Set @cf = CreateObject("ComplexFilterPart")
SetObjectProperty(@cf,"LeftOperand",@sf1)
SetObjectProperty(@cf,"RightOperand",@sf2)
SetObjectProperty(@cf,"LogicalOperator","AND")

/* set the filter to the request */
SetObjectProperty(@rr,"Filter",@cf)


SET @arrTrackingEventRows = InvokeRetrieve(@rr)

IF RowCount(@arrTrackingEventRows) > 0 THEN
Outputline(Concat(v("Has rows: "), RowCount(@arrTrackingEventRows)))
Else
Outputline(v("Has no rows."))
ENDIF

FOR @i = 1 to RowCount(@arrTrackingEventRows) DO
  SET @row = Row(@arrTrackingEventRows ,@i)
  SET @SendID = Field(@row ,'SendID')
  SET @CreatedDate = Field(@row ,'CreatedDate')
  SET @ModifiedDate = Field(@row ,'ModifiedDate')
  SET @SubscriberKey = Field(@row ,'SubscriberKey')
  outputline(concat("<br>SendID: ", @SendID))
  outputline(concat("<br>CreatedDate: ", @CreatedDate))
  outputline(concat("<br>ModifiedDate: ", @ModifiedDate))
  outputline(concat("<br>SubscriberKey: ", @SubscriberKey, "<hr>"))
NEXT @i

]%%
```

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying the DateValue on the filter and using xsd date format for date:

Replace existing:

> AddObjectArrayItem(@sf1, "Value", DateAdd("02/01/2016", "0", "d"))

with:

> AddObjectArrayItem(@sf1, "DateValue", FormatDate(DateAdd("02/01/2016", "0", "d")),"YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ" )

Comment: Mac, thank you for the suggested code, I'll have to give that a shot.  I was looking over the documentation again, and I think that the TrackingEvent object is not accessible to developers: https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/trackingevent/.  I guess if I want tracking event data, I'll have to tap into the OpenEvent/ClickEvent/etc... I wish there was a single place for that data.

Comment: Didn't catch that in the code.  You are correct that you can't retrieve the abstract TrackingEvent, it has to be a specific type like OpenEvent.